# Can I get audio version of UCSD dataset?

Tags: audio, video

I request to please tell me the source through which I can access audio version of UCSD dataset.
UCSD is an video anomaly based dataset.

Kindly guide me in this respect.
Regards,

Comment: Asking a search engine delivers *many* things for "UCSD dataset". You'll have to be much much more precise, and also: explain why you're not simply asking the UCSD folks?

Comment: will you please tell which search engine I should ask for?

Comment: I asked google and duck duck go. Notice that search results at least on google are *heavily* personalized. However, why does *my* search engine matter? Please be clear about what *you* are referring to!

Answer (score 2):

The DCASE community has since 2020 had a compoetition on Unsupervised Detection of Anomalous Sounds, with acommanying datasets. Here is the [2021 edition](https://dcase.community/challenge2021/task-unsupervised-detection-of-anomalous-sounds).